# Java Reverse a LinkedList -- Debugger wont even work

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So basically I created my own `linkedlist` class, and now I'm adding a function called `reverse` that reverses it. The strange thing is, it's not working and I can't even debug! I have no idea whats going on, if someone could pull my code and let me know whats happening that would be amazing. I have both my Node class and `LinkedList` class in one file, and the reverse function is called reverse. If you try to use reverse now, it doesn't work, freezes the debugger, and doesn't even let me step through the while loop after the first iteration. (I'm using `IntelliJ`)

```
class Node<Type> {

    private Type data;
    private Node<Type> nextNode;

    public Node(Type data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(Type data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Type getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setNextNode(Node<Type> nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    public Node<Type> getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Data: " + this.data;
    }
}

public class LinkedList<Type> {

    private Node<Type> head; 
    private int length; 

    public LinkedList() {
        length = 0;
    }

    // Returns: Pointer to the first Node in the list where Node.getData().equals(data)
    // O(N)
    public Node<Type> find(Type data) {
        Node<Type> currentNode = head; 
        while(currentNode != null) {
            if(currentNode.getData().equals(data)) {
                return currentNode;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        }

        return null;
    }


    // Returns: the length of the list
    // O(1) 
    public int getLength() {
        return length; 
    }

    // Create a node with data and add it to the front of the list
    // O(1)
    public void addAtHead(Type data) {
        Node<Type> newHead = new Node<Type>(data);
        newHead.setNextNode(this.head);
        this.head = newHead;
        length += 1;
    }

    // Delete the head node (garbage collection)
    // O(1)
    public void deleteHead(){
        if(this.head != null) {
            this.head = this.head.getNextNode();
            length -= 1;            
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {
        Node<Type> rememberMe = head.getNextNode();

        while(rememberMe != null) {
            Node<Type> temp = head;
            head = rememberMe;
            rememberMe = head.getNextNode();
            head.setNextNode(temp);
        }
    }

    // Print out the node using node.toString
    // Eg. { node1.toString() , node2.toString() , node3.toString() }
    // O(N)
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "{";
        Node<Type> currentNode = this.head; 
        while(currentNode != null) {
            result += " " + currentNode.toString() + " ";
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
            if(currentNode != null) {
                result += ", ";
            }

        }

        result += "}";

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: set a breakpoint in your while loop, you should see the cause.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work, after the first iteration it all ends! @Kent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reverse the original head still has a next that points back to what was the second element but now is the second to last so that after reversing you have a loop at the end. This means the toString() function has an infinite loop in it, which the intellij debugger is probably calling.

To fix, keep track of the original head and set its next to null.

```
public void reverse() {
    Node<Type> orig_head = head;
    Node<Type> rememberMe = head.getNextNode();

    while(rememberMe != null) {
        Node<Type> temp = head;
        head = rememberMe;
        rememberMe = head.getNextNode();
        head.setNextNode(temp);
    }
    orig_head.setNextNode(null);
}
```